# For Loop: changing the loop condition while it is looping

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

What I want to do is replace all 'A' in a string with "Bb". but it will only loop with the original string not on the new string.

for example:

AAA 
BbAA 
BbBbA

and it stops there because the original string only has a length of 3. it reads only up to the 3rd index and not the rest.

```
    Dim txt As String
    txt = output_text.Text

    Dim a As String = a_equi.Text

    Dim index As Integer = txt.Length - 1
    Dim output As String = ""

    For i = 0 To index
        If (txt(i) = TextBox1.Text) Then
            output = txt.Remove(i, 1).Insert(i, a)
            txt = output
            TextBox2.Text += txt + Environment.NewLine

        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: have you tried inbuild function of vb.net to replace string  output= input.Replace("A", "Bb")

Comment: Use a StringBuilder and create a new string appending the substitution string or the current char. Do not try to replace on the same input string.

Comment: Can you not just use a `while loop` ?.. You can do all the checking you want and string changes you want then leave the loop once you are satisfied..

Comment: I'm just an amateur in VB.NET so I only know the basics.

Comment: I'm not well equipped with while loop. Only For Loop.

Comment: I looked for pages explaining the While loop. They actually make it look more complicated than it is. I'd just look at how While loops are used in the answers on this page because it's pretty intuitive, slightly simpler than a For Next loop. In "English" it's saying, "While some condition is true, do these things." Then read the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh1f56zs.aspx).

Comment: @MazoKisto see the first comment above - That will do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this leaves us looking for a `String.ReplaceFirst` function. Since there isn't one, we can just write that function. Then the code that calls it becomes much more readable because it's quickly apparent what it's doing (from the name of the function.)

```
Public Function ReplaceFirst(searched As String, target As String, replacement As String) As String

    'This input validation is just for completeness.
    'It's not strictly necessary.

    'If the searched string is "null", throw an exception.
    If (searched Is Nothing) Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("searched")

    'If the target string is "null", throw an exception.
    If (target Is Nothing) Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("target")

    'If the searched string doesn't contain the target string at all
    'then just return it - were done.
    Dim foundIndex As Integer = searched.IndexOf(target)
    If (foundIndex = -1) Then Return searched

    'Build a new string that replaces the target with the replacement.
    Return String.Concat(searched.Substring(0, foundIndex), replacement, _
        searched.Substring(foundIndex + target.Length, searched.Length - (foundIndex + target.Length)))
End Function
```

Notice how when you read the code below, you don't even have to spend a moment trying to figure out what it's doing. It's readable. While the input string contains "A", replace the first "A" with "Bb".

```
Dim input as string = "AAA"
While input.IndexOf("A") > -1
   input = input.ReplaceFirst(input,"A","Bb")
   'If you need to capture individual values of "input" as it changes
   'add them to a list.
End While
```

You could optimize or completely replace the function. What matters is that your code is readable, someone can tell what it's doing, and the `ReplaceFirst` function is testable.

Then, let's say you wanted another function that gave you all of the "versions" of your input string as the target string is replaced:

```
Public Function GetIterativeReplacements(searched As String, target As String, replacement As String) As List(of string)
    Dim output As New List(Of String)
    While searched.IndexOf(target) > -1
        searched = ReplaceFirst(searched, target, replacement)
        output.Add(searched)
    End While
    Return output
End Function
```

If you call

```
dim output as List(of string) = GetIterativeReplacments("AAAA","A","Bb")
```

It's going to return a list of strings containing

```
BbAAA, BbBbAA, BbBbBbA, BbBbBbBb
```

It's almost always good to keep methods short. If they start to get too long, just break them into smaller methods with clear names. That way you're not trying to read and follow and test one big, long function. That's difficult whether or not you're a new programmer. The trick isn't being able to create long, complex functions that we understand because we wrote them - it's creating small, simpler functions that anyone can understand.

Comment: Thank you very much for this! I have completed my program.

Answer (score 0):

Check your comments for a better solution, but for future reference you should use a while loop instead of a for loop if your condition will be changing and you're wanting to take that change into account.

I've made a simple example below to help you understand. If you tried the same with a for loop, you'd only get "one" "two" and "three" printed because the for loop doesn't 'see' that `vals` was changed

```
    Dim vals As New List(Of String)
    vals.Add("one")
    vals.Add("two")
    vals.Add("three")

    Dim i As Integer = 0
    While i < vals.Count
        Console.WriteLine(vals(i))
        If vals(i) = "two" Then
            vals.Add("four")
            vals.Add("five")
        End If
        i += 1
    End While
```

Comment: how will I use while loop to change the condition?

Answer (score 0):

I was going to write a while loop to answer your question, but realized (with assistance from others) that you could just `.replace(x,y)`

```
Output.Text = Input.Text.Replace("A", "Bb")

'Input = N A T O
'Output = N Bb T O
```

**Edit:** There is probably a better alternative, but i quickly jotted this loop down, hope it helps.

You've said your new and don't fully understand `while loops`. So if you don't understand `functions` either or how to `pass arguments` to them, I'd suggest looking that up too.

*This is your Event, It can be a Button click or Textbox text change.*

```
'Cut & Paste into an Event (Change textboxes to whatever you have input/output)

    Dim Input As String = textbox1.Text

    Do While Input.Contains("A")

        Input = ChangeString(Input, "A", "Bb")

        ' Do whatever you like with each return of ChangeString() here

    Loop

    textbox2.Text = Input
```

*This is your Function, with 3 Arguments and a Return Value that can be called in your code*

```
' Cut & Paste into Code somewhere (not inside another sub/Function)
Private Function ChangeString(Input As String, LookFor As Char, ReplaceWith As String)

    Dim Output As String = Nothing
    Dim cFlag As Boolean = False

    For i As Integer = 0 To Input.Length - 1
        Dim c As Char = Input(i)

        If (c = LookFor) AndAlso (cFlag = False) Then
            Output += ReplaceWith
            cFlag = True
        Else
            Output += c
        End If

    Next

    Console.WriteLine("Output: " & Output)
    Return Output

End Function
```

Comment: this will replace all 'A' at the same time. I want to do it one by one.

Comment: Not sure if edits show up on your emails as changed or not, but I've edited my answer to suit your requirements. Tested and Works, You can remove the While loop if you just want to do it manually over and over, It will remove and replace whatever you specify as arguments

Answer (score 0):

If you do want to replace one by one instead of using the Replace function, you could use a while loop to look for the index of your search character/string, and then replace/insert at that index.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim a As String = String.Empty
    Dim b As String = String.Empty
    Dim c As String = String.Empty
    Dim d As Int32 = -1
    Console.Write("Whole string: ")
    a = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.Write("Replace: ")
    b = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.Write("Replace with: ")
    c = Console.ReadLine()

    d = a.IndexOf(b)
    While d > -1
        a = a.Remove(d, b.Length)
        a = a.Insert(d, c)
        d = a.LastIndexOf(b)
    End While
    Console.WriteLine("Finished string: " & a)
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Output would look like this:

```
Whole string: This is A string for replAcing chArActers.
Replace: A
Replace with: Bb
Finished string: This is Bb string for replBbcing chBbrBbcters.
```